# Example of closed kinematic chains in URDF - gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find an example of a closed-kinematic-chained robot description (in URDF) to be simulated in gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136371/example-of-closed-kinematic-chains-in-urdf---gazebo/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Closed kinamtic chains can not be described by URDF. You have to 'open up' your structure and take care about the constraints using software code that provides the joint coordinates.

Gazebo supports closed chains through SDF:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7308/parallel-robots-implementing-close-kinematic-chains/

---

Originally posted by [Peter Galambos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3465/peter-galambos/) with karma: 46 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2